# HTML DOM check if the text of an element includes specific text?

Tags: javascript, html

How to check if an element's `innerHTML` includes "as me to" (the whole phrase and not just if it includes one of the words)?
I know that it is pretty short, but the question is already stated in the title.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. A couple questions. First, what is it that you "would also"? Looks like you didn't finish the first sentence of your second paragraph. Second, are there any javascript libraries that you're using already like jquery? If so, please add that information to your question as that information can be relevant to answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexOf()

```
var str = $('some selector id').innerHTML();
var result = str.indexOf("as");
```

if result is -1 then there is no instance of "as" in the given string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using `RegExp`. If the element has given string, the `test()` function will return `true` or `false` if it's not.

```js
function check(elem, str) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML,
      rg = new RegExp(str, 'g'),
      res = rg.test(element);
      console.log(`Does the ${elem} element contains ${str} - ${res}`);
      return res;
}

check('p', 'as');
check('p', 'something');
```

```html
<p id='p'>ashamed</p>
```

Comment: thanks! but i need it in an if statement and that function does not seem to return anything.

Comment: @sostack Done. It will now return `true` or `false`, depending if there's given string or not.

Comment: @sostack What's up? Doesn't my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

HTML

```
<div id="source">this word as </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var sourceEl = document.getElementById('source');

if (sourceEl.textContent.includes('as'))
{
alert("Exist");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3zkzy1g/5/

Comment: thanks yes it works but i want to to check if it every word in the phrase I will search for, like "as next for". So the element 's text must hold this whole text and not just one single wordl..